# Why does the result contain multiple copies of the same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

With the following JavaScript, why does the output contain multiple copies of the same value?

```
reduce = function(docs) {
  var values = [];

  docs.forEach(function(doc) {
    if (values.indexOf(doc.value) != -1) return;

    values.push(doc.value.toDateString());
  });

  return values;
}

doc = {value: new Date("2012-01-01T00:00:00Z")}

reduce( [ doc, doc ] )
// => ["Sat Dec 31 2011", "Sat Dec 31 2011"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your verfication is wrong.

It should be `if (values.indexOf(doc.value.toDateString()) != -1) return;`

Comment: Thanks, Uzi! Much appreciated. Clearly I should've gone to bed rather than kept hacking last night  =P

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce = function(docs) {
    var values = [];
    if (values.indexOf(doc.value.toDateString()) != -1) return;
    values.push(doc.value.toDateString());
    return values;
}

doc = {value: new Date("2012-01-01T00:00:00Z")}
reduce(doc)

//["Sun Jan 01 2012"]
```

Try this. Why are you doing a foreach function if you only want one passed through? You should also only be passing `doc` through once to the reduce function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kyle. The code in the problem is a simplified example. The real code in my application will be passing many docs to reduce(), some of which will contain duplicate values in the "value" property.